# How to convert int to double and vice-versa when parsing using num.parse?

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
void main() {
  print(foo<int>('1'));
  print(foo<double>('1.0'));
  print(foo<double>('1'));
  print(foo<int>('1.0'));
}

T foo<T extends num>(String s) {
  final res = num.parse(s);
  return (T == double ? res.toDouble() : res.toInt()) as T;
}
```

As you can see I'm manually handling the types. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Well, I am not smart enough. I will go back to library.

Comment: I wonder, what's the point of this exercise? You need to include the type parameter `T` of `foo<T>()` in the source anyway, so why not have separate functions for `int` and `double`?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want a class that handles both `int` and `double`, I think that's the sort of thing that you will need to resort to doing.  However, I'd use `return (T == double ? double.parse(s) : int.parse(s)) as T;` instead so that `foo<int>('3.9')` generates an error instead of being silently truncated (unless that's behavior you specifically want).

Comment: @Ber Yes, that would be better if that's an option.  You could imagine, however, a similar problem could arise in a non-trivial generic class.

Comment: @jamesdlin Well, in that case I'd consider that a case of really bad design. The whole point of generics and class inheritance is to avoid checking for types and special cases.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for confirming. And yes, I needed to make `foo<int>('1.0')` work, that's why I used `toInt()` there.

Comment: @Ber In general, I'd agree, but `num`s are kind of annoying to deal with, and there are only two possible concrete classes, so I think a special case is acceptable.

Comment: @Ber I don't want to make two functions because I have a widget which accepts a `T extends num` type and returns a value `T` after calling `foo`.

Comment: @iDecode You could derive two widget classes, one for each type. Or you pass in the appropriate version of foo as an arg.

Comment: @Ber if I derive two widget classes and put the logic in a superclass then still I'll be dealing with `num`. Sorry, I didn't get you by passing the appropriate version of `foo`.

Comment: @iDecode Maybe this is a question that is too focused on a particular solution to a more abstract problem. If you ask a question about designing your widgets, maybe you'll get a much besser answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a *much* better solution. You have a function which changes behavior entirely based on the type argument. Since all you can do with a type argument is subtype-checks, or comparing it to a constant type literal, you need to do something like that.

I'd prefer subtype-checks, because that also allows promotion, but for something limited like this, where there are only four possible types for `T`, checking `Type` object equality can also work. There'll just need to be at least one `as T` before returning.

Either approach also *only* works for type hierarchies which are finite, and you account for all the possible types. Even here, the current code is not covering `<num>` and `<Never>` which are also valid type arguments for the bound `num`. So, be vigilant.

Maybe, using subtype checks for promotion:

```dart
T parse<T extends num>(String source) {
  var value = num.parse(source);
  if (value is T) return value;
  // T is not `num`.
  num d = value.toDouble();
  if (d is T) return d; // T was double.
  try {
    num n = value.toInt(); // Can fail for Infinity/NaN
    if (n is T) return n; // T was int
  } catch (_) {
    // T was `int` after all, so throwing was correct.
    if (1 is T) rethrow; // T was int, but the input was not valid.
  }
  // T was neither num, double, nor int, so must be `Never`.
  throw ArgumentError.value(T, "T", "Must not be Never");
}
```

Or. using `Type` object equality:

```dart
T parse<T extends num>(String source) {
  var value = num.parse(source);
  switch (T) {
    case num: return value as T;
    case int: return value.toInt() as T;
    case double: return value.toDouble() as T;
    default: 
     throw ArgumentError.value(T, "T", "Must not be Never");
  }
}
```