# How to use type parameter when using redirecting constructor?

Tags: dart

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```dart
class Foo<T extends num> {
  final T t;
  Foo._(this.t);
  Foo.zero() : this._<int>(0); // Error
}
```

> '' isn't a field in the enclosing class.

**Note:** I want to do it without casting, i.e. `this._(0 as T)` works but I want to use type argument `int`.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense.  What would `Foo<double>.zero()` do?  Redirecting to a `Foo<int>` constructor would return an object with a different type.

Comment: Additionally, the `0 as T` cast would compile but would fail at runtime for `Foo<double>.zero()` with the Dart VM. [As has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75161291/), making generics that work with both `int`s and `double`s is unfortunately annoying, and you basically need to check the value of `T`.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the reason why `<int>` is not allowed. Currently, I am using `as` with my custom `typedef` to make it work.